# Change order with flexbox and allow some items to wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a responsive layout. For the narrowest screen width I need to switch the order of the 2nd and 3rd items.

I can do this with flexbox but I can't then see how to let the rating and link wrap onto the same line.

```
<header>
  <h1>Long heading text is here</h1>
  <div class="rating">Rating here</div>
  <p class="name">Someones name</p>
  <p class="link">www.someting.com</p>
</header>

header {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  order: 1;
}
.name {
  order: 2;
}
div {
  order: 3;
}
.link {
  order: 4;
}
```

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVpPPB

Comment: TBH...I'm pretty sure that final image isn't really possible even with flexbox. Elements just don't wrap like that. Plus breaking links isn't optimal.